# Confused with discordjs + twitter api

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, discord, discord.js

to get straight to the point, ive never been so confused... this command was mapped out to be easy and simple which is *exactly* how it went until this issue.

when grabbing a name on discord ex < $twit jack > it works just fine but when its faced with longer ids like mine, it just throws 3 random numbers at the end

ex: my actual twitter id (1054084643346137089) | what my bot displays (1054084643346137100)

as you see it just throws random numbers for the last 3

you could test it yourself on https://tweeterid.com/

code -

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const request = require("node-superfetch");
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");
const bearer =
  ""; // empty only for this

module.exports = {
  name: "twit",
  aliases: ["twitter", "twitid"],
  description: "This command allows admins to grab twitter user ids.",
  /**
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {Message} message
   * @param {String[]} args
   */
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const username = args[0];
    if (!username)
      return message.channel.send("You must provide a username to search for.");

    try {
      const { body } = await request
        .get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json")
        .set({ Authorization: `Bearer ${bearer}` })
        .query({ screen_name: username });

      message.channel.send(
        `Twitter ID For ${username}: http://www.twitter.com/I/user/${body.id}`
      );
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.status === 403)
        return message.channel.send(
          "This user either went private or deactivated their account."
        );
      else if (error.status === 404)
        return message.channel.send("Couldn't find this user.");
      else return message.channel.send(`Unknown Error: ${error.message}`);
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: do you have a question of some kind?

Comment: Please don't host your code on external sites, and instead edit your question to include your code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). External links tend to change/break and nuke value for future visitors to your question.

Comment: More to the point, it sounds like your code is converting this identifier to its integer representation at some level and you're running into precision issues, as the resulting integer exceeds [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). Don't cast it to an `int` anywhere in your code and keep it as a string

Comment: how could i do that though? most standard ids now exceed 16 chars

Comment: use string instead of number to store IDs

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Twitter is using a signed 64 bit integer for storing the user ID. This number is greater than 53 bits ([`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)) and JavaScript has difficulty interpreting it. It can only safely represent integers between -(2<sup>53</sup> - 1) and 2<sup>53</sup> - 1.

Luckily, Twitter's [user object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/user) also provides the string representation of the unique identifier as `id_str`. As the docs mention; *"Implementations should use this rather than the large, possibly un-consumable integer in id"*.

So all you need to do is use `id_str` instead of `id`:

```js
const body = {
  id: 1054084643346137089,
  id_str: '1054084643346137089'
}

console.log(`Twitter ID: http://www.twitter.com/I/user/${body.id}`)
console.log(`Twitter ID: http://www.twitter.com/I/user/${body.id_str}`)
```